# Plot a random open set with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to plot a random set with TikZ?

[image]

Comment: To down-voters: please do not down-vote without commenting. This question needs improvement, but it is not necessarily obvious to a new user what they are expected to do! @OP Please show us the code you've got and explain the specific difficulty you're having doing what you want. Do-it-for-me questions are not really fair ones to ask. If your image is appealing, often somebody will use it for purposes of procrastination, but if nobody takes a fancy to it it will just languish and be eventually closed. Answers are also usually more helpful when we know where you're starting from.

Comment: In this particular case, I don't even know what you need. Something which just looks like a blob? Something pseudo-random? Really random? Should it be randomised on every compilation? Maybe 'random set' has a specific meaning to you, but to me it could mean anything: a set chosen at random from a specified set of sets; a set with n elements each randomly chosen from the universe of all non-sets; a set containing a random number of red balls; the set of Dickens's novels drawn in a random way; a random interpretation of a 'random set' from the set of all possible interpretations ...

Comment: What is a random ___open___ set?

Comment: @PaulGaborit I didn't notice that the subject of the question didn't match the text. Mind you, I'm confused enough by the generic concept of a random set, so maybe that's just as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mostly works OK...

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\foreach \i in {0,...,2}\foreach \j in {0,...,2}
  \draw [blue!50!cyan, dashed, ultra thick, shift={(\j*6,\i*6)}] 
    plot [smooth cycle, tension=1, domain=0:320, samples=18] (\x:{2+rand/2});
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are these random sets _open_ ?

Comment: These are just shapes. Interpretation is left to the OP.